# jmeter-maven-plugin Configurations are not Working

Tags: maven, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm trying to automate this build.

This is my pom portion:

```
<configuration>
     <resultsDirectory>pm-test/jmeter/results</resultsDirectory>
     <testFilesDirectory>pm-test/jmeter/scripts</testFilesDirectory>
     <appendResultsTimestamp>true</appendResultsTimestamp>
     <resultsFileNameDateFormat>yyMMddHHmmss</resultsFileNameDateFormat>                    
</configuration>
```

But when I execute Mave/Install this is the log:

> *[info] Raw results: /Users/talosdigital/Documents/workspace/jmeter-demo/target/jmeter/report/loyaltySurround-151223.jtl*
>
> *[info] Test report: /Users/talosdigital/Documents/workspace/jmeter-demo/target/jmeter/report/loyaltySurround-151223.jtl-report.html*

The issues are:

1. It's not generating the reports in the folder
2. It's not using the specified date format for result files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using?  The entire plugin definition from your POM would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using version 1.10.1. I was using 1.4.1. Thanks all for your help.